# Unable to log event.target (using Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When this code runs, I get the error, 'Cannot read property 'target' of undefined'. I want to find the background color of the element clicked on. I was told because my css is not inline, I need to use getComputedStyle (I am using Chrome). But at line 11, (or console.log(event.target)) the error is thrown. Why can't I even log the event I clicked on?

```
var options = document.getElementsByClassName("options");

for (var i = 0; i <options.length; i++) {
    options[i].addEventListener("click", color_select(event), false)
}

function color_select(event) {

    //this is the line that the error occurs on
    console.log(event.target);
    var e = event.target;
    console.log(e);
    var bgColor = getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor;
    console.log(bgColor);   
}
```

Comment: stop in debug-mode and look at the value "event" has. maybe it has no target-property

Comment: Dont invoke the function `color_select(event)`. Just pass the reference of the function like `options[i].addEventListener("click", color_select, false)`

Comment: The first thing that should have puzzled you is where `event` comes from when you call the function with `color_select(event)`. `(...)` after a function reference **always** calls the function. `foo(bar())` will call `bar` first and pass its *return value* to `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding the event listener correctly. Do this:

```
options[i].addEventListener("click", color_select, false)
```

The event will be passed to the function by default. But keep in mind that neither `event.target` will not work in IE8 and neither will `addEventListener`.

Your code has the following problems:

```
options[i].addEventListener("click", color_select(event), false)
```

It calls the function color_select and passes the variable `event`, which at this point is not defined. Then it tries to attach the return value of the function (undefined) to the event listener. That's why it's not working.

Comment: Missing `event.target` in IE8 doesn't matter, IE8 doesn't support `addEventListener` either.